# Gnu radio synchronization of packets. Comparing received modulated signal with the signal which is decoded and encoded again (Mean error square)

Tags: gnuradio

I am facing some issues when I try to compare the received signal with the signal that has been decoded and encoded again (BPSK is used).
I have tried to add delay to the signal that goes through a shorter path but it seems like the delay between the two signals is not constant and it is "sliding" as time passes.

I am using packet communications.

I can send the files to anyone that has an idea about this issue.
[Transmitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyZbr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtE7u.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDrGE.png)